# Loop through inputs and add them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to loop through all the inputs, when more are added, and add them all to the total (var = paidTotal). I'm getting NaN for the total and Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Pretty sure the issue is in the peoplepaid() function.

In the peoplePaid() onclick function I'm trying to loop through all the fieldInputs (class="person") depending on how many inputs are created and add the total to #paidTotal. Hopefully that's helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxFields = 20;
  var addButton = $('#plusOne');
  var deleteButton = $('#minusOne');
  var wrapper = $('#userNumbers');
  var fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" class="persons"/></div>';
  var x = 1;

  $(addButton).click(function() {
    if (x < maxFields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append(fieldInput);
    }
  });

  $(deleteButton).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myNode = document.getElementById("userNumbers");
    i = myNode.childNodes.length - 1;
    if (i >= 0) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.childNodes[i]);
      x--;
    }

  });

});


function peoplePaid() {
  var checkTotal = document.getElementById('check').value;
  var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons').value;
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('persons');
  var paidTotal = document.getElementById('paidTotal');

  for (var i = 1; i < personsCheck.length; i += 1) {
    paidTotal[i] += personsCheck;
  }
  paidTotal.innerHTML = checkTotal - personsCheck;


}
```

```html
<h3>Check Total</h3>
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />
<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<button type="button" onclick="plusOne()" id="plusOne">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="minusOne()" id="minusOne">-</button>


<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="text" class="persons" name="person">
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="peoplePaid()">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey OP, welcome to SO. Check out the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question (1) to include an actual question, and (2) to include an [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code

Comment: Thanks benvc. In the peoplePaid() onclick function I'm trying to loop through all the fieldInputs (class="person") depending on how many inputs are created and add the total to #paidTotal. Hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: One thing you'll need to do is parse the string input values to numbers so that you can do the numeric addition.  Look here for details:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: Your 'length' error is from `personsCheck.length`.  When you defined `personsCheck` you used a `.value' which didn't work (returned undefined).  You need to set a breakpoint inside the function so you can step through and look at the values as the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting Cannot read property 'length' of undefined is because

```
var personsCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('persons').value;
```

will return undefined.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('persons')
```

will return an array of DOM elements and arrays do not have a value property. Then when you access

```
personsCheck.length
```

in the loop you get Cannot read property 'length' of undefined because personsCheck is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a bit but I used  map to get an array of the values then summed them up using reduce

run the snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const maxFields = 20;
  const wrapper = $('#userNumbers');
  const fieldInput = '<div><input type="text" name="persons" class="persons"/></div>';
  const reducer = (a,c) => parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(c,10);

  $('#plusOne').click(() => 
    $("#userNumbers .persons").length < maxFields &&
    $(wrapper).append(fieldInput));
    
  $('#deleteButton').click(()=> $("#userNumbers .persons").last().remove());
  
  $('#peoplePaid').click( () => {
  const arr= $("#userNumbers .persons").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
   }).get();
   $('#paidTotal').html(arr.reduce(reducer));  
   })
  
});
```

```html
<h3>Check Total</h3>
$ <input type="text" id="check" value="" />
<h3>Number of People: <span id="numberOfPeople"></span></h3>

<button type="button"  id="plusOne">+</button>
<button type="button"  id="minusOne">-</button>


<div>
  <div id="userNumbers">
    <input type="number" class="persons" name="person">
  </div>
</div>


<button id="peoplePaid">Calculate</button>
<!--Paid Amount-->
<div>
  <h3>Paid Amount: <span id="paidTotal"></span></h3>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```